# How to get RFC 3339 formatted datetime in string value with millisecond precision in GO lang

Tags: go, time, rfc3339

I want to get current time in UTC in RFC 3339 format (string value) with millisecond precision in GO lang.

```
Ex. "timestamp": "2023-10-18T20:43:20.542Z".
but i am getting  2009-11-10T23:00:00Z
```

I looked at a link which mentioned "Rather than add more inconsistency, it seems like **t.Round(time.Millisecond).Format(time.RFC3339Nano)** is very clear and equivalent to what we'd provide with an explicit RFC3339Milli.".

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/36472 where they mentioned to use

I tried some format but i did not get what i am looking for.
Am i doing anything wrong ?
https://go.dev/play/p/Dmxkte9sAEz

Comment: Did you test this in playground? With `000` as msecs? That will remove zeros, so try `999`. Also, try outside playground with a nonzero msec.

Comment: Yes i tried it here. https://go.dev/play/p/Dmxkte9sAEz

I used below timeformat which i got from google search
const timeFormatRFC3339Milli = "2006-01-02T15:04:05.999Z07:00"

Comment: Displayed on the front page of the playground: `In the playground the time begins at 2009-11-10 23:00:00 UTC` -- run your code on a system with real time which will have non-zero milliseconds. (or create a time instant yourself, or sleep some amount to shift the clock https://go.dev/play/p/bwl6Mq4UkLC)

Answer (score -2):

I was able to get what i was looking for. I am in different locale and playground provided UTC time so there was difference in format from playground and my code(I had missed to get UTC time).

First get the time in UTC format and then provide format which will provide and it works.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

const timeFormatRFC3339Milli = "2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z07:00"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(time.Now().UTC().Format(timeFormatRFC3339Milli))
}
```

Comment: UTC has nothing to do with milliseconds in the format; you are padding the milliseconds with 0s here, while in your first example you are not.